# promise with .catch() rejected but appears as fulfilled in Promise.allSetteled

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is the simplified version of the problem;

there are some promises, few `.then()` chains, and a `.catch()` block for error handling; 
each promise might resolve or reject hence I use `Promise.allSetted` to know which promise had been failed based on their order in array and their status; It works fine when all promises resolve but when a promise is rejected, it's status will be shown as "fulfilled" in `Promise.allSetteld`; If I remove the `.catch()` block, It will work as expected but we need to keep the `.catch()` block for logging to the store; So why isn't it just behave as expected? is there any way to make it show "rejected" status with `.catch()` block?

```js
let a = Promise.resolve("a: Promise.resolved").then(response => response).catch(err=>console.log(err));

let b = Promise.reject("b: Promise.rejected").then(response => response); // no error handling

let e = Promise.reject("e: Promise.rejected").then(response => response).catch(err=>console.log(err));

Promise.allSettled([a,b,e]).then( values => console.log(values) );
```

Comment: "So why isn't it just behave as expected?" well if you catch w/o rethrow it is "expected" to have no error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *throw* the error from the `catch` block, so that the error is not handled in the `catch`:

```js
let a = Promise.resolve("a: Promise.resolved").then(response => response).catch(err => console.log(err));

let b = Promise.reject("b: Promise.rejected").then(response => response); // no error handling

let e = Promise.reject("e: Promise.rejected").then(response => response).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  throw err;
  //or Reject the Promise
  //return Promise.reject(err)
});

Promise.allSettled([a, b, e]).then(values => console.log(values));
```

This is also discussed in the Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch):

> `p.catch(onRejected)`;
>
> `onRejected`
>
> > A `Function` called when the `Promise` is rejected.
> >
> > This function has one argument: `reason` The rejection reason. The Promise
> >     returned by `catch()` is rejected if `onRejected` throws an error or
> >     returns a `Promise` which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is ***resolved***.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah now I understand, we `.catch()` it! 
so by using `.catch()` (or catch in `try{}catch(e){}`) we are telling the program: "Don't panic, everything is under control", " I'll handle that". and that make sense now. if we handle it without throwing errors it sounds like everything is fine; so yeah, why not; it should be `fulfilled`