# Why does using catch on Promise.reject() change it to a fulfilled promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Today I was just exploring Promises in JavaScript and I came across this:

`Promise.reject("Failed");`

Gives

```
Promise { <state>: "rejected", <reason>: "Failed" }
Uncaught (in promise) Failed
```

Whereas,

`Promise.reject("Failed").catch((reason) => console.log(reason));`

Gives

```
Failed
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }
```

I get the part that in the latter, the rejection is caught  and hence just a normal console message but why is the promise itself changed to fulfilled when it was rejected.

Comment: Because it has been: the `catch()` handler literally fulfills the rejected promise, there is now nothing left that "can be done to the promise".

Comment: It seems unnatural though as the task wasn't "fulfilled" .

Comment: there's nothing natural about programming languages: a promise is considered "fulfilled" when it has yielded all the data it should yield. When you reject the promise, there's still data left on the table, and it's not done yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [promise with .catch() rejected but appears as fulfilled in Promise.allSetteled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259694/promise-with-catch-rejected-but-appears-as-fulfilled-in-promise-allsetteled)

Comment: @NeerajKumar "*It seems unnatural though*" no, it's mirrors `try { someFn(); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }` - when you have this code, the execution continues after the `try`/`catch` *as if* there was no error. Because you caught and handled it.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `.catch` will return a *pending* promise.

Whether that pending promise will *fulfill* depends on:

1. The promise on which it is called. It that promise fulfils, then the `catch` promise will just follow suit and resolve to the same outcome without ever executing the callback that was passed as argument.
2. If the promise on which it is called is rejected (like in your example), then the callback (passed to `catch` as argument) is executed. This execution determines how the `catch`-returned promise (that was pending) is resolved. For instance, if the callback throws an error, that promise will actually get in a rejected state.

Demo:

```js
let p = Promise.reject();

let q = p.catch(() => {
    console.log("p rejected");
    // Return a promise that will reject 1 second later
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000));
});

let r = q.catch(() => {
    console.log("q rejected!");
});
```

Comment: Can a promise get rejected automatically (without `.reject()`)  just like errors can come up without explicitly `throw`ing them?

Comment: @NeerajKumar it could be. If there is an error that shows up while a handler is executed (via explicit `throw` or not), that will reject the promise. Also, possible if you use `Promise.all()` and one of the promises is rejected, then the promise returned by `Promise.all` will also be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Every `Promise.then` and `Promise.catch` returns a fulfilled promise with the value returned from the `function` handler given to `then` or `catch` clause.

Let's take a look at your code.

```js
Promise.reject("Failed").catch((reason) => console.log(reason));
```

The first `Promise.reject("Failed")` returns a rejected promise with the value "Failed". The `catch` clause has an arrow functions. And what is this arrow function returning you may ask? The value returned by `console.log` which is undefined.

How do you test it you may ask? Simple, paste this in your console.

```js
Promise.reject("Failed").catch((reason) => {
 console.log(reason);
 return "Whoa, what is this?";
});
```

Comment: It returns a fulfilled promise.

Comment: @NeerajKumar Yes, you are correct. I've edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks a bunch.